# regular expression for single quote mark in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

in mongodb shell client,
how can I query to find documents with single quotes?
I escaped the quote mark in regex.
but it does not work.

```
db.coll.find({field: /\'/})
```

Comment: Just `/'/` should work, so should `/\'/`. Are you sure you're not looking for a Unicode character that just looks like an ASCII single quote?

Comment: @muistooshort they don't work

Comment: @HaveAGuess: Yes they do work, just tried it in the MongoDB console.

Comment: @muistooshort well it's two to one at the moment, so something is going on .. I was running in script mode not console mode.

Comment: @HaveAGuess: Sorry, I don't know what to say, worked for me in the console a couple years ago and still works for me. Is there a shell involved somewhere? Or something else that would interpret quotes or backslashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.coll.find({field: /\x27/});
```

Where 0x27 is [Unicode APOSTROPHE](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html)

From [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Internationalized+Strings):

> MongoDB regex queries support UTF-8 in the regex string.