# How do I escape single quote / apostrophe when using Springboot Query annotation on a MongoDBRepository

Tags: regex, mongodb, spring-boot, annotations, escaping

I am using a MongoDBRepository interface to perform a lookup on a database. I am using the Spring @Query annotation to do the lookup but any input string which includes a single quote breaks things.

I have tried escaping the single quote using single, double, quadruple slashes, I have tried using double single quotes but nothing seems to work.

My MongoDBRepository method definition looks like this:

```java
@Query(value = "{'name' : {$regex : '^(?0)$', $options: 'i'} }")
public Result findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
```

If I pass in the value as *John's Pizza* I get the following in the console:

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found 'Pizza'.
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:132) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:149) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.readValue(DocumentCodec.java:222) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:151) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:105) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:90) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery.<init>(BasicQuery.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:140) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:85) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.findByNameIgnoreCase(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.benwwest.schuman.service.MerchantService.findByNameIgnoreCase(MerchantService.java:468) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.benwwest.schuman.controller.MerchantController.postCreateMerchant(MerchantController.java:177) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.benwwest.schuman.controller.MerchantController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ee0273f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.benwwest.schuman.controller.MerchantController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b777b848.postCreateMerchant(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:63) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
```

I have tried modifying the input to:

*John\'s Pizza*

*John\'s Pizza*

*John\\'s Pizza*

*John\u0027s Pizza*

but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any guidance on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally coming back to answer my own question, 2 years later!

I ran into this issue again recently I and did some more searching and found another article that had the answer:

[regular expression for single quote mark in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494372/regular-expression-for-single-quote-mark-in-mongodb)

So keeping the @Query the same as the original in the question:

```
@Query(value = "{'name' : {$regex : '^(?0)$', $options: 'i'} }")
public Result findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
```

and when I call the method, I just need to modify the input query, replacing and single quotes with \\x27, e.g.

```
String cleanedName = searchName.replaceAll("'","\\\\x27").trim();       
Result result = myRepo.findByNameIgnoreCase(cleanedName);
```

Answer (score 0):

See, you are writing like: `regex : '^(?0)$'`
So when you replace ?0 with John's Pizza. It will use single quote in a different way:  `'^(John'` and `s)$` Something like this.
Solution is: you should use double quotes in query instead of single quote:

```
@Query(value = "{'name' : {$regex : \"^(?0)$\", $options: 'i'} }")
public Result findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
```

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work. Because the value of the @Query annotation is a string it has to be surrounded in double quotes so I cant use double quotes inside this to define the regex value (as it will terminate the first double quote.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesnt work either. The application crashes at a startup - ```Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'name' : {$regex : "^("_param_0"[ ]*)$", $options: 'i'} }
                        ^
 at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:302) ~[mongodb-driver-3.8.2.jar:na]
 at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:273) ~[mongodb-driver-3.8.2.jar:na]
 at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:228) ~[mongodb-driver-3.8.2.jar:na] ```

Comment: it seems that it has converted \" to " only